# Percentage Difference Using CASE WHEN clause

Tags: sql, postgresql, case

The table I am working with is called 'transactions'. The columns are id (customer id), amount (amount spent by customer), timestamp (time of purchase).

I am trying to query:

- yesterdays revenue: sum of amount.
- percent difference from 8 day's ago revenue to yesterday's revenue.
- MTD.
- percent difference from last months MTD to this months MTD.

**SAMPLE DATA**

| id | amount | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 50 | 2021-12-01 |
| 2 | 60 | 2021-12-02 |
| 3 | 70 | 2021-11-05 |
| 4 | 80 | 2022-01-26 |
| 5 | 90 | 2022-01-25 |
| 6 | 20 | 2022-01-26 |
| 7 | 80 | 2022-01-19 |

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

| yesterday_revenue | pct_change_week_ago | mtd | pct_change_month_prior |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0.25 | 270 | 0.50 |

**This is my code. The percent change columns are both incorrect. Please help.**

```
select

-- yesterday
sum(case when timestamp::date = current_date - 1 then amount else null end) yesterday_revenue,

-- yesterday v. last week
(sum(case when timestamp::date > current_date - 1 then amount else null end) - sum(case when timestamp::date = current_date - 8 then amount else null end))
/ sum(case when timestamp::date = current_date - 8 then amount else null end) pct_change_week_ago,

-- mtd
sum(case when date_trunc('month',timestamp) = date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE -1) then amount else null end) mtd,

-- mtd v. month prior
(sum(case when date_trunc('month',timestamp) = date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE -1) then amount else null end) - sum(case when date_trunc('month',timestamp) = date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE -1) - interval '1 month'
      and date_part('day',timestamp ) <= date_part('day', CURRENT_DATE -1) then amount else null end))
    / sum(case when date_trunc('month',timestamp) = date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE -1) - interval '1 month'
      and date_part('day',timestamp ) <= date_part('day', CURRENT_DATE -1) then amount else null end) pct_change_month_prior

from transactions
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. Please edit your post and include the schema of relevant columns in the transactions table and also show some sample data.

Comment: Hello @FlexYourData please see my the table info i have added. Thanks!

Comment: please post sample data and expected result.

Comment: @Philippe  I have added SAMPLE DATA and EXPECTED OUTPUT. please help. Thanks!

Comment: @FlexYourData I have added SAMPLE DATA and EXPECTED OUTPUT. please help. Thanks!

Comment: The sample data doesn't allow for the results to be produced (no data on Jan 19). Can you change the sample data to be the data that produces the results you expect? Thx

Comment: @FlexYourData I have updated the sample data. Thanks for pointing that out. basically (new - old) / old does not seem to work...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some things to consider:

- "yesterday vs last week" currently uses `timestamp::date > current_date - 1` at the start. This will include transactions from today only, not yesterday (it says "greater than yesterday"). I think it should be `timestamp::date = current_date - 1`
- I could be wrong here, but I think `sum(case when date_trunc('month',timestamp) = date_trunc('month',CURRENT_DATE -1)` will capture transactions on the current date as well if the current date is in the same month as yesterday. You may not want that.
- As far as I can tell, 'pct_change_month_prior' should be `1.45`, not `0.5`. You have `110` in December and `270` in January. `270 - 110 = 160` and `160 / 110 = 1.45`. Your existing query already returns that result. FWIW, you can also use `new/old-1` to get the same result in a slightly simpler way.

Comment: Ah, that's what I was missing, the operator! The last point might not be what they want - a positive number for imrpovements and negative for reductions is easier to read than a ">100" number and a "<100".

Comment: @flexyourdata Thanks for this. How do I query the % difference December MTD and January MTD?

Comment: @Dizz - what calculation are you expecting for "% difference December MTD and January MTD". Could you comment with how you would calculate and end with 50% by hand? December MTD = 110. January MTD = 270. Difference is 160. This is 145% of December.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so really, it's about your maths in the `SELECT` part of your statement.

Amount changed is: `new - old`

As a multiplicative amount, it is `(new - old) / old` or `new / old - 1`

As a percentage, you need to multiply by 100... `100 * (new / old - 1)` but I understand you aren't worried about this.

Further to this, let's make sure your new and old are correct.

Yesterday's sum:

```
sum(case when timestamp::date = CURRENT_DATE - 1 then amount else null end)
```

8 days ago sum:

```
sum(case when timestamp::date = CURRENT_DATE - 8 then amount else null end)
```

1 month to yesterday sum:

```
sum(case when timestamp::date > CURRENT_DATE - 1 - INTERVAL '1 month' AND timestamp::date <= CURRENT_DATE - 1 then amount else null end)
```

1 month to 1 month and 1 day ago sum:

```
sum(case when timestamp::date > CURRENT_DATE - 1 - INTERVAL '2 month' AND timestamp::date <= CURRENT_DATE - 1 - INTERVAL '1 month' then amount else null end)
```

Start of month to yesterday sum:

```
sum(case when timestamp::date > DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE - 1) AND timestamp::date <= CURRENT_DATE - 1 then amount else null end)
```

Start of yesterday's last month to a month ago yesterday sum:

```
sum(case when timestamp::date > DATE_TRUNC('month', CURRENT_DATE - 1 - INTERVAL '1 month') AND timestamp::date <= CURRENT_DATE - 1 - INTERVAL '1 month' then amount else null end)
```

It's important you don't change `=` to `>` or cropping to just the date part else you will include more than you really want.

Effectively, by cropping to the month part, it would almost always sum all transactions for two months.

Comment: I have done (new - old) / old for each...

Comment: For example: look at '-- yesterday v. last week'. I have done (yesterday - 8 days ago) / 8 days ago.

Comment: it doesnt really matter about the % because I use a visualiser that turn it into %. The actual figure is wrong

Comment: instead of getting '0.25' for 'pct_change_week_ago' i am getting '20'

Comment: That sounds like the numbers are round the wrong way somewhere...

Comment: Thanks - How do I query the % difference December MTD and January MTD?

Comment: Ah, you want the first to the 25th of January compared to first to the 25th of December... that gets trickier, but sure, I'll oblige.

Comment: @Dizz I've added those now, too. Fairly simple, it still uses the same idea of a value being between two others.

Comment: Thanks a lot. 1 more cheeky query if you dont mind.. do you know why this doesnt work: count(case when (timestamp::date = current_date - 1) then id else null end)
    / count(case when (timestamp::date = current_date - 8) then id else null end) -1 ... I am trying to find the % diff of  customers who ordered yesterday compared customers who ordered a week ago from yesterday?

Comment: @Dizz count will count null in the same way it counts not null values. You'll also be counting multiple orders for the same customer as individual records. You need some way to count unique and not null, but I suggest asking that in a new question.